# Combine numbers to 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 rows, I need to sum 1 column together and make 1 row. Is this possible?

I really just need these 2 rows...

[image]

To combine into this row. Only difference is the Pay_Amount fields are summed.

[image]

I'm at the point where I have the rows isolated using partition by but am not sure where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: Show the query you are using. Hint: `SUM()` ... `Group By`

Comment: Assuming you want to group them by location:
     select sum(Pay_Amount) as Paid from your_table_name Group By Location
or group by client_no:
select sum(Pay_Amount) as Paid from your_table_name Group By client_no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function.

```
select Location, client_no, MAX(Price), MAX(Tax_1), MAX(Tax_2), SUM(Pay_Amount)
from table
group by location, client_no
```

Comment: First() ?  OP tagged SQL Server

Comment: Dang it.  Thanks.  Not sure where I got FIRST from actually. haha

Comment: There is [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You also don't need the `MAX` **if** you move those columns to the `GROUP BY`. It will make the result set distinct.

Comment: He may want those values in the result set (which is what he indicated in the post).

Comment: This will work Tom. Thank you so much for the reply!